Value return null when scene is changed
When player finish the game i have to keep stats of the player so i do it in script but when scene is get changed value return null even its in the DontDestroyOnLoad type script so i call the method first here
`
private IEnumerator LevelCompleteSequence(Transform player)
    {
        player.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().enabled = false;
        yield return MoveTo(player, bottom.position);
        yield return MoveTo(player, player.position + Vector3.right);
        yield return MoveTo(player, player.position + Vector3.right + Vector3.down);
        yield return MoveTo(player, castle.position);
        GameManager.Instance.GetRenderer();
        player.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        GameManager.Instance.LoadLevel(nextWorld, nextStage);
    }

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
    public static GameManager Instance {get; private set;}
    public  PlayerSpriteRenderer activeRendererGameManager;
    private void Awake()
    {
        if (Instance != null)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(gameObject);
        } else {
            Instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
    }
    public void GetRenderer()
    {
        //launch first to get renderer launch on flagpole.cs
        Player player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
        activeRendererGameManager = player.activeRenderer;
        Debug.Log("GetRenderer activeRendererGameManager : " +   activeRendererGameManager.ToString());
        //value return successfully
    }
    public void LoadLevel(int world, int stage)
    {
        this.world = world;
        this.stage = stage;
        
        SceneManager.LoadScene($"{world}-{stage}");

        // Activate the scene loader panel for 3 seconds
        Invoke("PlayerSpriteGet", 0.02f);
        
        Debug.Log("LoadLevel activeRendererGameManager : " +   activeRendererGameManager.ToString()); // value return successfully

    }

    public void PlayerSpriteGet()
    {
        //launch as second to change active sprite on scene
        Debug.Log("Playerspriteget activeRendererGameManager : " +          activeRendererGameManager.ToString());
        // Return null 
        Player player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
        player.activeRenderer = activeRendererGameManager;
    }   



and here my GameManager and related function on it
Try to change order of the function or remove the Invoke but when i try remove the Invoke i get  error probably because of the  scene still not loaded when scene get changed only activeRendererGameManager value return null i have other value as int they don't change or don't return null

I asume you are speaking about the Awake method?
If so, then tell me where it is called.

No sorry for missunderstanding i'm trying keep the value of player.activeRenderer on
activeRendererGameManager because the Player reset on every scene but GameManager not i guess

I'm confused. So where do you get the null value, on the PlayerSpriteGet method?

when i try the call the PlayerSpriteGet method i check the activeRendererGameManager value with debug.log but it's empty so that's my problem i need the keep activeRendererGameManager value but it's return null when scene get changed

in my code activeRendererGameManager keep the reference of the Player.activeRenderer but when scene changed Player script get destroyed and restarted with new scene so that's why activeRendererGameManager return null. but still don't know how to fix it

Look if in some place you are destroying the Player object.
